# Adding an image path via the db in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, postgresql

I currently have a show page pulling the content from postgres and this includes a main image using a standard image_tag to the file path:

`<%= image_tag(@coffeeshop.image_path,class:'img-fluid') %>`

This works perfectly and shows the image just fine.
However I would also like to include other images on a post by post basis to be inserted inline with the copy so don't want to use further fixed tags in my show page, but rather just add them in when I create each individual post.

I have tried standard html `img src` tags and also the ruby tag `image_tag` but it just prints the raw code in the page.

I am using `==` in my tag and have got other html tags such as `<p>` and `<h2>` to work correctly.  Just can't get an image to show!

Comment: show the views snippets which contents `img src`.

Comment: I don't have them anymore, but was trying to write 
`<img src="https://www.gourmetcoffee.london/assets/images/morty_390.jpg" />`

Comment: what do you mean `==` ? have you tried .html_safe or raw ?

Comment: <%== %> allows to process the html code in the rails tag. Opposed to <%= %>